# EditForm in Blazor with two InputSelects, submit button doesn't seem ike it fires

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor

I have two InputSelects that get their options from two tables. Their values write to another table that's basically a lookup table. So, two integer values, and an ID for that row.

```
@page "/utility/ptrh"
@inject IProviderTypeRespiteHomeRepo Repo
@inject IRespiteHomeRepo RhRepo
@inject IProviderTypeRepo PtRepo
@inject NavigationManager NavManager
@inject IToastService ToastService

<h3>Assign Provider Type to Respite Home</h3>

<EditForm Model="_model" OnSubmit="CreatePtrh">
    <DataAnnotationsValidator />
    <ValidationSummary />
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="rh">Respite Home</label>
        @*<InputNumber @bind-Value="_model.RespiteHomeId"></InputNumber>*@
        <InputSelect @bind-Value="_model.RespiteHomeId" class="form-control" id="rh">
            @if (_rhModel != null)
            {
                <option value="-1">select one</option>
                @foreach (var rh in _rhModel)
                {
                    <option value="@rh.ID">@rh.RespiteHomeName</option>
                }
            }
        </InputSelect>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="pt">Provider Type</label>
        @*<InputNumber @bind-Value="_model.ProviderTypeId"></InputNumber>*@
        <InputSelect @bind-Value="_model.ProviderTypeId" class="form-control" id="pt">
            @if (_ptModel != null)
            {
                <option value="-1">select one</option>
                @foreach (var pt in _ptModel)
                {
                    <option value="@pt.ID">@pt.ProviderTypeName</option>
                }
            }
        </InputSelect>
    </div>
    
    <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit"><span class="oi oi-pencil"></span> Add Provider Type for Respite Home</button>

    <button @onclick="BackToList" class="btn btn-outline-secondary">
        <span class="oi oi-media-skip-backward"></span> Back to List
    </button>
</EditForm>

@code {
    private ProviderTypeRespiteHome _model = new ProviderTypeRespiteHome();
    private IList<RespiteHome> _rhModel;
    private IList<ProviderType> _ptModel;
    private bool _isSuccess = true;

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        _rhModel = await RhRepo.Get(Endpoints.RespiteHomeTypesEndpoint);
        _ptModel = await PtRepo.Get(Endpoints.ProviderTypesEndpoint);
    }

    private async Task CreatePtrh()
    {
        _isSuccess = await Repo.Create(Endpoints.PTRHEndpoint, _model);
        if (_isSuccess)
        {
            ToastService.ShowSuccess("PTRH record has been created.");
            BackToList();
        }
    }

    private void BackToList()
    {
        NavManager.NavigateTo("/respitehomes/");
    }
}
```

My data models are OK. They pull the data from the other two tables OK. Just when I hit the submit button, nothing happens.

Help! Other create razor pages with almost the same markup work!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As in the comment above, make sure you don't have MORE THAN ONE controller in your API that has the exact same name, even if it's in another folder or sub-folder. Once deleted, it works just fine.